# How to draw scree plot of first 2 principal components

Tags: r, pca

Below is my scree plot for principal components of the covariance matrix of Airquality inbuilt dataset. How to draw scree plot for only first 2 principal components?

Principal components(cumulative):

```
cum_cov <- cumsum(PC_cov)
cum_cov

[1] 0.4119637 0.6034876 0.7613283 0.8912956 0.9622555 1.0000000


#Covariance matrix scree plot

cov_matrplot <- qplot(c(1:6), cum_cov) + geom_line() + xlab("Principal Component") + 
ylab("test")+ ggtitle("Scree Plot") + ylim(0,1)
cov_matrplot
```

Comment: did you try changing first part to `qplot(c(1:2), cum_cov[1:2])` ?

Comment: Why would you want to? Surely the point is to plot enough PCs  to see where the elbow is.

Comment: @Samet Sokel Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): x  This is the error I get since number of variables is 6 I think

Comment: You did not follow @Samet Sökel exactly. Changing your code to `cov_matrplot <- qplot(c(1:2), cum_cov[1:2]) . . .` works just fine.